# TensorFlow word embedding model + LDA Negative values in data passed to LatentDirichletAllocation.fit

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, lda, word-embedding, topic-modeling

I am trying to use a pre-trained [model](https://tfhub.dev/google/nnlm-en-dim128/2) from TensorFlow hub instead of frequency vectorization techniques for word embedding before passing the resultant feature vector to the LDA model.

I followed the steps for the TensorFlow model, but I got this error upon passing the resultant feature vector to the LDA model:

```
Negative values in data passed to LatentDirichletAllocation.fit
```

Here's what I have implemented so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow_hub as hub

from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/nnlm-en-dim50-with-normalization/1")
embeddings = embed(["cat is on the mat", "dog is in the fog"])
lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=2, max_iter=50)
lda = lda_model.fit_transform(embeddings)
```

I realized that `print(embeddings)` prints some negative values as shown below:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[ 0.16589954  0.0254965   0.1574857   0.17688066  0.02911299 -0.03092718
   0.19445257 -0.05709129 -0.08631689 -0.04391516  0.13032274  0.10905275
  -0.08515751  0.01056632 -0.17220995 -0.17925954  0.19556305  0.0802278
  -0.03247919 -0.49176937 -0.07767699 -0.03160921 -0.13952136  0.05959712
   0.06858718  0.22386682 -0.16653948  0.19412343 -0.05491862  0.10997339
  -0.15811177 -0.02576607 -0.07910853 -0.258499   -0.04206644 -0.20052543
   0.1705603  -0.15314153  0.0039225  -0.28694248  0.02468278  0.11069503
   0.03733957  0.01433943 -0.11048374  0.11931834 -0.11552787 -0.11110869
   0.02384969 -0.07074881]
```

But, is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `fit` function of `LatentDirichletAllocation` does not allow a negative array, I will recommend you to apply [softplus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function#:%7E:text=displaystyle%20C%5E%7B%5Cinfty%20%7D%7D-,Softplus%5B8%5D,-%7B%5Cdisplaystyle%20%5Cln%20%5Cleft) on the `embeddings`.

Here is the code snippet:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from tensorflow.math import softplus

from sklearn.decomposition import LatentDirichletAllocation

embed = hub.load("https://tfhub.dev/google/tf2-preview/nnlm-en-dim50-with-normalization/1")
embeddings = softplus(embed(["cat is on the mat", "dog is in the fog"]))

lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=2, max_iter=50)
lda = lda_model.fit_transform(embeddings)
```